# Install Wine and PlayOnLinux on server environments

Tags: server, wine, playonlinux, debian

Well, I'd like to follow the following tutorial on a server environment: https://eltallerdemiku.blogspot.com/2018/12/como-instalr-loquendo-en-linux-con.html

The point here is that I think I'm not allowed to do such thing on a server environment because of the graphical requirements of this program (but maybe, is there any option to run a graphical app on a server environment?).

Is there any way to copy out these files PlayOnLinux created into a new server environment, something like exporting the environment and reimport it again?

I won't use any kind of graphical interface, so this is not a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application that needs a desktop environment, you can install a DE from the command line.  The typical package for the GNOME3 desktop on Ubuntu is `ubuntu-desktop`, but you might be interested in something lighter like `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` or `lubuntu-desktop`.

You can install the desktop environment with the following commands:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```